# CodeIgniter Initial Page Load Variable?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm looking for a solution to loading the header/footer/navigation only on the initial page view.

The reasoning behind this is that my navigation panel uses Ajax to render the content of the destination link in the main content div instead of actually loading the page itself.

However, I need to be able to say something along the lines of if its the initial view, load the header, navigation, then the actual page, then the footer. But if its not the initial view and the page is loaded in the content div area so for example a navigation link or a form submit, it doesn't load the header, navigation and footer but only the actual page.

So for example I have these 4 views:

header_view
navigation_view
page_a_view
footer_view

And this controller:

controller_a

The navigation has a link which is 'Page A' and points to http://myurl.com/controller_a. If that link is clicked I only wanted controller_a to load the page_a_view view, because the navigation link will load the data of that page into the div.

However if I directly go to http://myurl.com/controller_a, it needs to render the the header/navigation/footer also.

The solution I thought I was on the right lines with was something like a base controller with a function load_page() which would be something like:

```
function load_page($page, $data) {

    if($this->uri->segment($this->uri->total_segments()) == "initial_page_load") {
        $this->load->view('header_view');
        $this->load->view('navigation_view');
        $this->load->view($page, $data);
        $this->load->view('footer_view');
    } else {
        $this->load->view($page, $data);
    }

}
```

So if I was to go to http://myurl.com/controller_a/initial_page_load it would load the header/navigation/footer but if I went to http://myurl.com/controller_a it wouldn't.

However this doesn't cover all possibilities.

Another way I thought of is checking if there is a referring URL, if there is, don't load the header/navigation/footer. But again, this doesn't cover things such as what if the link was referred by an external website?

Does anyone have any suggestions to how I can achieve what I need?

Comment: Not quite sure on the reasoning for a downvote...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm still testing this it seems to be doing exactly what I expect so far! It's one of those ones which is simple but does the complete job so hopefully no problems pop up...

In MY_Controller.php

```
function load_page($page, $data) {
    if(!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        $this->load->view('header_view');
        $this->load->view('navigation_view');
    }
    $this->load->view($page, $data);
    if(!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        $this->load->view('footer_view');
    }
}
```

Managed to stumble across that function when looking in the Input class documentation

Answer (score 1):

Let this be your view page for all views. For your other pages, you are going to change the content on div, 'page_content' dynamically via ajax.

```
**application/views/your_template_view.php**
<?php
    $this->load->view('header_view');
    $this->load->view('navigation_view');
?>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id='home' class='my_links'>Home</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id='about_us' class='my_links'>About us</a>

<!--
    Make sure the id of the page is same as 
    the file name of view page for respective pages
 -->

<div id='page_content'><?php echo $page_content; ?></div>

<?php
    $this->load->view('footer_view');
?>
<script lang='javascript'>
    $('.my_links').click(function(){
        $.post(
            '<?php echo site_url('test_controller/get_page_content') ?>',
            {'page_content':$(this).attr('id')},
                function(response){
                    if(response != '')
                        $('#page_content').text(response);
                },'json'
        );
    });
</script>
```

Let this be your controller :

```
**application/controller/test_controller.php**
function your_page($param1 = '', $param2 ='') {
    /*this one is for your initial page*/
    if($param1)
        // send mail
    if($param2)
        // send mail 
    $data['page_content'] = $this->load->view('initial_page_load');
    $this->load->view('your_template_view', $data); 
}
function get_page_content()
{
    /*this one is for other pages, this provides page content 
      for the request made from ajax*/
    $page_title = $this->input->post('page_title');
    $page_content = $this->load->view($page_title);
    echo json_encode($page_content);
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean, however I can't just have a single initial page for reasons such as an email that gets sent out which includes links such as http://www.myurl.com/controller_a/method_1/param_a/param_b

Answer (score 0):

Make a session variable to denote whether the header/footer is loaded, and if it is, just skip them

```
if (!$this->session->userdata('nav_loaded')) {
    $this->load->view('header_view');
}
```

etc...

This will work for all your pages, no matter where are they called from, provided that all the post-initial calls are done by AJAX.

EDIT

If you want to mix ajax and non-ajax calls after that, the session varable won't work, of course. Perhaps you could put an ajax parameter in your urls and adjust the controllers according to that.

```
public function index($ajax = false) {
...
    if (!ajax) {
        $this->load->view('header_view');
    }
    etc...
}
```

So, all the AJAX call will have that additional parameter in the url set to true (almost anything except zero: `index/1`, `index/ajax`, etc.).

Comment: Where would you suggest removing the session though? As if I loaded a page initially, it created the session, so the content page I access through a navigation link doesn't load the navigation link - If i then go directly to a content page the session would exist and I would be left with a page with no header/navigation/footer

Comment: Never remove it - the downside being that you'd have to load the pages by ajax... If you want to mix ajax and no-ajax, perhaps you could put an ajax parameter in your urls and adjust the controllers according to that.

Comment: That is the route I thought would solve my problem, however it's where to have that parameter in the URL. If I just have it as the last parameter in the URL, and I don't specify a method within a controller, such as myurl.com/controller1/ajax_true then it looks for the method ajax_true.

Comment: But that's okay because you'll need `index` (`myurl.com/controller1/index/whatever`) only when making ajax calls, your regular url will still be `myurl.com/controller1` because the ajax paremeter in the controller is false by default. No ugly URLs.